# Python 3 Websockets, how to properly close socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, python-asyncio

I have the following class for opening my websockets:

```
import os
import asyncio  
import websockets
import threading

class Server:

    def get_port(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_PORT', '9002')

    def get_host(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_HOST', 'localhost')

    def shutdown(self):
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)

    def start(self):
        return websockets.serve(self.handler, self.get_host(), self.get_port())
```

Followed by some async handling methods for incoming messages. The loop function for getting the messages runs in its own thread, just for information.

I am able to terminate the program, however I was not able to close the sockets properly, cause it causes the following error on the restart of the script

```
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 9002):
```

Since the port is already in use. Usually I would use some `.close()` function, however the websocket package does not provide such function, so I am wondering if I can get this done with the os package or the websocket package?

Answer (score 2):

The proper shutdown process is discussed [here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#graceful-shutdown). The basic idea is to use the `serve()` method as an async context manager.

```
async with websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 9002):
    await stop
```

For example, `stop` can be a `Future`. The `await` "returns" when you call [`stop.set_result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.set_result). The context manager will then shutdown the server gracefully.

Usually, you would use a signal handler to trigger the stop condition (an example is also included in the docs).

You also might get the error, when the socket is not opened with `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` by the framework. [See this question for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

Comment: Thank you, your mentioned solution did not work for me, since I am on windows. However your provided link showed a solution, which worked, thank you